# Passing correct Info to Dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I am looking at creating a `Dialog` with a `bundle of data`. This all work correctly.
I have a number of `buttons` when clicked opens the `dialog` with the data and can then be updated.

Trouble I am having is it does not matter which button I press the bundle is only the data for the last row. Any ideas on getting the correct data passed to the `Dialog` for each button.

I was thinking down the line of setting an id for each view as I pass through the loop but unsure how to call that back again

Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nameInfo.size(); i++) {
            // creating the views
            View viewItem = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_item, null);
            nameView = (TextView) viewItem.findViewById(R.id.title);
            nameView.setId(i);
            value1View = (TextView) viewItem.findViewById(R.id.value1);
            value1View.setId(i);
            value2View = (TextView) viewItem.findViewById(R.id.value2);
            value2View.setId(i);

            updateButton = (Button) sightmarkView.findViewById(R.id.updatebutton);
            updateButton.setId(i);
            // Getting the values
            nameValue = nameInfo.get(i).toString();
            value1 = db.getvalue1('1', nameInfo.get(i).toString());
            value2 = db.getvalue2('2', nameInfo.get(i).toString());
            // update fields
            nameView.setText(nameValue);
            value1View.setText(String.valueOf(value1));
            value2View.setText(String.valueOf(value2));

            updateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    int updateButtonId = updateButton.getId();

                                bundle = new Bundle();
                                bundle.putString("name", nameValue);
                            bundle.putFloat("value1", value1);
                                bundle.putFloat("value2", value2);

                                showDialog(SIGHTMARK_DIALOG_ID, bundle);

                }
            });
        pMainlayout.addView(viewItem);
}
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each loop (from the `for`), you are redefining the values of `nameValue`, `value1` and `value2`.

To fix the problem, just change your code to match this:

```
// Getting the values
final String nameValue = nameInfo.get(i).toString();
final String value1 = db.getvalue1('1', nameInfo.get(i).toString());
final String value2 = db.getvalue2('2', nameInfo.get(i).toString());
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609609/creating-final-variables-inside-a-loop/609611#609611