# How to pass data between activities using static variables on a public class?

Tags: android, android-activity, static, glsurfaceview

I'm trying to use static variables on a public class for passing them between activities.

I'm having a rare problem doing that. I'm giving values to the static variables on a activity. This activity calls a GLSurfaceView and listen for screen orientation changes.

If i give values to the static variables on the GLSurfaceView, then, all works fine, the values are stored and i can retrieve them when the onCreate method is called again after a screen orientation change.

The problem is when i store values on the static variables outside the GLSurfaceView class, inside the onTouchListener methods of the activity. These values are not stored properly on the static variables, because when i try to access them on the GLSurfaceView those values are not what they were supossed to be.

This is my static variables class:

```
public class MagazineStatus {
//clase utilizada para almacenar variables estáticas.   
static int currentPage=1; //página actual   
//Valores originales cuando pasamos de un modo a otro, por ejemplo, de portrait a landscape.
static float oScale=0.0f;
static float oX=0.0f;
static float oY=0.0f;
static float oZrot=0;   
static boolean modeChanged=false; //indica si hemos cambiado de modo 
(landscape/portrait)    
}
```

Here i'm storing the values on my activity class (i did a debug and aparently they are being stored correctly):

```
        for (int i=0;i<thumbnailLinearLayouts.size();i++){
        final int auxIndex=i;
        thumbnailLinearLayouts.get(i).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                MagazineStatus.currentPage=auxIndex;
                System.out.println("MagazineStatus.currentPage: "+MagazineStatus.currentPage);
                return true;
            }                               
        });
    }
```

And here i'm trying to retrieve these values on the GLSurfaceView class, and the values are not correct, It is retrieving the original initial value, 1, instead of the value stored before.

```
currentPage=MagazineStatus.currentPage;     //cargo datos guardados antes del cambio de orientación
```

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Huh, you declare a variable final than keep re-assigning to it (`auxIndex`). Whats going on there?

Comment: that works, there is not the problem

Comment: @elevine - I was wrong about the `final` part, per this question+answer.n Good to kow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609609/creating-final-variables-inside-a-loop

Comment: @CodyCaughlan I misread i for 1, so I was wrong too :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If Android kills and restarts the process for your application, then the static variables will get assigned to their default values.  You might be better of using `SharedPreferences` instead of static variables: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Comment: yes, sharedPreferences are another way to do it, but i want to learn to use static variables to achieve this. I'm sure there is a way to achieve this.

Comment: Given the way that Android manages the lifecycle of your application, it may not be the best choice to use static variables for sharing data between activities.

Comment: Well there is a better option to save instance variables i.e via `onSaveInstanceState` and get later via `onRestoreInstanceState | onCreate`. The purpose of `SharedPreferences` is to store kind of data that app might need after weeks!

Comment: @MuhammadBabar that could be part of an alternative solution to solving the question.  They would still  need to decide on a mechanism for passing the data between the activities though.  I still believe `SharedPreferences` is a valid choice.  As the docs state, its "a general framework that allows you to save and retrieve persistent key-value pairs of primitive data types"

Answer (score 2):

define variable as public static and then use it throughout entire application,

eg

```
public static String xyz = "abcd";
```

now in any class to use 'xyz' just use it as under

```
classname.xyz;
```

Comment: i tryed putting public but no changes, the problem is still here

Answer (score 0):

**Second Activity**  :-

In xml File take one textview field

**Java Code**

```
public static String name;

TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

t.setText(name);
```

**First Activity**:-

in xml file take one edittext and one button

**Java Code**

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener){

    @override
    public void onClick(View v){

    SecondActivity.name=editText.getText().toString();

    Intent i=new Intent(firstActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);

    startActivity(i);

    }
}
```