# Safety and Reliability of Sharing data between Android Activities using shared Object ownership

Tags: android

`A` and `B` are Activities and both hold a reference to an object `C`

Is it safe (meaning not adversely effected by Android Lifecycles, nor by Activities being on different processes/threads) to share `C` in such a way ?

For example, `A` sets `C.q="What is the answer?"`and `B` later sets `C.a="42"`.

Would that be safe/reliable with respect to Android Life cycles or if the Activities are running in different processes (or threads) ?

EDIT:

This is a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637761/how-to-pass-data-between-activities-using-static-variables-on-a-public-class).

Comment: Kindly explain how you are sharing C between A and B?

Comment: I pass a reference to `C` to `A` and to `B` on creation, or it is also possible that `C` is accessible from `A` or `B` as a static field.

Comment: In first scenario  you are referring to passing data as intent. Well if you pass data via intent the object copy is passed rather than the actual reference, so you need to call activity B with startActivityForResult so that you can send back the result to A. Second case, if C is static then it will live as long as the `Application` process is alive. It totally depends upon the architecture and design of the app. Using best practices will always ensure the safeness of data.

Comment: In the first scenario I refer to passing data not by intent but by traditional object field initialization, when `A` and `B` are created, they get the same `C` injected as a dependency.

Comment: you mean like new A(c)? Sorry i don't have much knowledge about dependency injection.

Comment: Yes, as A(c) and as B(c). Injected as dependency is my fancy way of saying : passed as argument to a constructor.

Comment: In android we don't create activities like this. So this way of passing arguments to activities is not the best/recommended way in android. You have two options either use intents or static reference.

Comment: Right, but what can go wrong with static reference ? ( which is - in effect - the same as passing the same reference via object constructor to two different objects )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122275/discussion-between-muhammad-babar-and-jhegedus).