# Looping through an array of nodes to add a MouseEvent that affects an external variable

Tags: arraylist, javafx, event-handling, mouseevent

I have an arraylist of HBox nodes that need to work sort of like a set of radio buttons. Clicking on any of the nodes will update an int value corresponding with the clicked-on node's position in the array.

It's an array list because the number of HBox nodes needs to be dynamic and determined upon runtime based on arguments. Each HBox is identical in format but the contents of the labels inside are unique.

Looping through the arraylist (arrayOfHBox) to add a Mouse click event to each node produces the problem of inner classes not accepting non-final variables (so inside the mouse event I can't tell what position of the array I'm at). I understand the reasons why this must happen, but I'm not sure of an alternative approach to get around it.

```
int selectedIndex=-1; //the int to determine which "radio button" HBox is clicked

for (int i=0;i<arrayOfHBox.size();i++)
{
    arrayOfHBox.get(i).addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() 
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) 
        {
            selectedIndex=i;  //Won't compile
            event.consume();
        }
    });
}
```

The question then: is there a way to add mouse handlers to all the HBox nodes where each would set an external variable equal to the clicked-upon node's position in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then e. g. use a final intermediate variable like

```
int selectedIndex=-1; //the int to determine which "radio button" HBox is clicked

for (int i=0;i<arrayOfHBox.size();i++)
{

    final int index = i;
    arrayOfHBox.get(i).addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() 
    {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) 
        {
            selectedIndex=index;  //Won't compile
            event.consume();
        }
    });
}
```

or work on object level, use event.getSource() to determine the source and pick the hbox as item of the arraylist.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, that worked great. I didn't know I could use final variables inside a for loop, so I did a quick search on it and found [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609609/creating-final-variables-inside-a-loop), which may be of some help to others curious of how a final variable works inside a scope like I was.