# Variable "i" as Final variable

Tags: java, android, for-loop

I am asking this question for my clarification.

I am having a for loop inside of which I have some inner method.
when I used **"i"** in this inner method the IDE keeps asking me to make it **"i"** as final.

```
for(int i=0; i<array.size();i++) {

     some innermethodcode(){
     Log.e("array",""+array.get(i)); // it says me make it final;

    }
```

What would happen if I declared "i" as global like

> int i ;

;
or what would be different if I declared "i" as

> int i = 0;

And use it as

```
for(i=0; i<array.size();i++) {

         some innermethodcode(){
         Log.e("array",""+array.get(i)); // it says me make it final;

        }
```

would it result in completly unpredictable values of "i" because the place that uses it is not executed the same time the loop runs ?

**EDIT**

I am very much knowing about how to get a final variable from a loop variable like this:

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
>     final int j = i;
>     // now you can use j instead
> }
> ```

My question is **why** i need to make final and what would happen if I declared it as global.

Please help me to clarify this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/609611

Comment: why cant you define method outside and call it by passing an array or array item as you want

Comment: By inner method do you mean inner class??? There's no concept of inner methods in java or android...

Comment: @Sree : The above link won't answer my answer. So i can't be duplicate as i guess.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mistaking is for an anonymous inner class. Have a look at this stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class).

Comment: This should be posted as a comment not an **answer**

Comment: @shaswat - please note that AbhishekAsh does not have enough reputation to write comments. And by the way, this is a very useful link :)

Comment: Yeah , i wanted to comment but StackOverflow denied me

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter where you declare it, it needs to be `final`. The way to use a loop index like this is to use a second variable.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    final int j = i;
    // now you can use j instead
}
```

Comment: I don't do java at all, just curious: Is it possible like this: for (final int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { ?

Comment: No, that won't compile because you can't do i++ for a final variable. It's very annoying, but you really do need a second variable.

Comment: Ahh, yeah, I forgot about the i++, ofcourse it does not work, thanks :)