# Apache POI setting cells to 0

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI to generate cells but I'm noticing that it seems to set all my cells to the same value. In this case 0. I don't really see why. When I am about to save my sheet to file I can see that the cells have values, but when looking at the generated file it is empty. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a screen of the debugging when I can see that some cells have values(such as the "5" in the debug window):

[image]

Here is the code I am using to generate the sheet:

```
@Override
public void generate(TableRepresentation tableRepresentation) {
    int rows = tableRepresentation.getRows();
    int columns = tableRepresentation.getColumns();
    final HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    final HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {

        final HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            row.createCell(j).setCellValue(tableRepresentation.get(i, j));
        }

    }

    try {
        final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("tjockis.xls");

        workbook.write(fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("tjockis.xls" + " written successfully");

}

public interface TableRepresentation {
    int getRows();

    int getColumns();

    String get(int i, int j);
}
```

EDIT:

Here is how the exported sheet looks:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you make any variable as **final**, you cannot change the value of final variable(It will be constant).

A **final** variable may only be assigned to once and its value will not change and can help avoid programming errors.

Once a **final** variable has been assigned, it always contains the same value. If a **final** variable holds a reference to an object, then the state of the object may be changed by operations on the object, but the variable will always refer to the same object.

Comment: And how is that a problem? Final is only limited to the scope it is defined in.

Comment: @why_vincent even if it limited to scope if it is assigned for first time that value can not be changed. Remove all your final keyword and try. Put the final keyword only where constants are required

Comment: 1: Look at the debug window, the cells have different values. How can that have happened if they have not been assigned to different values?

2: Tried what you said anyway but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @why_vincent Sorry if not working. I have posted general truth about final keyword from java doc.Did you remove all the 4 final keyword that in the above code. Mainly at this code you have to remove final HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(i); where you are assigning 0 default values. Good luck

Comment: That is not true though. Look up scope and final. It doesn't work the way that you think. This post proves my point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609609/creating-final-variables-inside-a-loop

Comment: You are right, you can see one answer in the post says "for each iteration in the loop, you are creating a new variable. The variables do share the same name, but that's fine because they are not in the same scope" . But in your case you are doing for a same scope where you are writing into a sheet. Hence final is not required i think . Did you try removing all 4 places and tried ?

Comment: They are not in the same scope since it is a different iteration, same as my example. I tried it as mentioned above. There is no difference. Final in this scenario is only a security, giving my a guarantee that I don't reassign the variables anywhere else. Removing it changes nothing in execution.